# Another Basic Integration Question, Possibly By Substitution

Tags: integration

What's the integral of $f(x)=(1-x^2)^{1/2}$? I tried making $x=\sin(t)$ and doing integration by substitution but I don't think I arrived to the correct answer. All responses are appreciated...

Comment: Perhaps it involves the use of arcsinx?

Answer (score 3):

Putting $x=\sin\theta$

$$\int\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=\int\cos^2\theta d\theta=\int\frac12(1+\cos2\theta) d\theta$$

$$=\frac{\theta+\frac{\sin2\theta}2}2+C$$

$$=\frac{\theta+\sin\theta\cos\theta}2+C$$

$\theta=\arcsin x,\cos\theta=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Answer (score 2):

[Integrating by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) with $u(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2},dv(x)=1$

$$I=\int\sqrt{1-x^2}\cdot1dx=\sqrt{1-x^2}\int dx-\int\left(\frac{d(\sqrt{1-x^2})}{dx}\cdot \int dx\right)dx$$

$$=x\sqrt{1-x^2}-\int\frac{(-2x)}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}xdx$$

$$=x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\int\frac{1-(1-x^2)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$$

$$=x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\int\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx-I$$

$$\implies 2I=x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\arcsin x+C$$

Comment: @JonathanY., have you noticed the $x$ with dx, which came as $\int dx$

Answer (score 2):

Recall the three most common [trigonometric substitutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution) and how they proceed.

Let $x=\sin\theta$. Then $\,dx = \cos\theta \,d\theta$. And $\theta = \arcsin x$.

$$\begin{align} \int\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx 
& =\int\sqrt{1 - \sin^2\theta}\,\cos\theta \,d\theta \\ \\ 
& =\int\sqrt{\cos^2\theta}\,\cos\theta \,d\theta \\ \\ 
& = \int\cos^2\theta \,d\theta \\ \\ 
& = \int\frac12(1+\cos2\theta) \,d\theta\\ \\ 
& =\frac12\Big(\theta+\frac{\sin2\theta}2\Big)+C\\ \\ 
& =\frac12\Big(\theta+\sin\theta\cos\theta\Big)+C \\ \\
& = \frac 12 \Big(\arcsin x + x\sqrt{1-x^2}\Big) + C\tag{$\dagger$}\end{align}$$

$(\dagger)$. Since $x = \sin \theta$, $\theta = \arcsin x$. And $\cos x = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$.
 
How do we know $\cos x = \sqrt{1-x^2}\;?\;$ 
Note: $\sin^2 \theta + \cos ^2 \theta = 1 = x^2 + (\sqrt{1 - x^2})^2 = x^2 + 1 - x^2$.

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks much for the support!

Comment: You are always welcome! :-)