# Yet Again, Another Basic Integration Question

Tags: integration

What's the integral of $f(x)=(1+x^2)^{1/2}$? I tried making $x=\sin(t)$ and doing integration by substitution but I don't think I arrived to the correct answer. Does this perhaps require the use of hyperbolic functions?

Comment: Try this way : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524468/another-basic-integration-question-possibly-by-substitution/524473#524473

Comment: What is your answer?  We can't tell if it is correct unless you share it. ;)

Comment: Consider $u=\sinh x$.

Comment: Well, actually, in this case, we can tell you if it is correct or not... try using $x=\tan(t)$.

Answer (score 3):

The choice for $x = \sin t$ would be appropriate if you had $\sqrt{1 - x^2}$.

But when you have an integrand containing $a^2 + x^2$, like here, where you have $\sqrt{ 1 + x^2}$, try substituting $x = a\tan t$.

In this case, that would be substituting $x = \tan t$. Then $dx = \sec^2 t\,dt$.

See Wikipedia for a quick refresher on the three most common [trigonometric substitutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution).

Answer (score 0):

So how about $x = \tan(t)$:

$$
\int \sqrt{1 + \tan^2(t)} \sec^2(t)\; dt = \int \lvert\sec(t)\rvert\sec^2(t)\;dt.
$$

Comment: I got to this point, but how do you solve the integral when it is |sect|(sect)^2

Comment: @LeonLeibovici: Assuming that $\sec(x) \geq 0$ you have the integral of $\sec^3(x)$. For this you can see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154900/indefinite-integral-of-secant-cubed